# Polite swearing words?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, offensive-language, euphemisms, minced-oaths

I hate to swear, i.e to say "fuck you" or whatsoever of those words. However sometimes I get angry and I wish there are words that could be a polite replacement for those swearing. I wish there's a polite way to say "That was so fucking hard". I want to express such a frustration or so with a polite word but with the same strength of expression. & I actually wonder what would a good author use as a way to make such a strong expression.

So my questions:

1 - what words could I use to swear in a polite way?

2- how would a good author swear in a good book?

Comment: If they are polite, they aren't swearing.

Comment: Shakespeare was quite good at it, and you can [be good at it too](http://www.pangloss.com/seidel/shake_rule.html)! Insults and expletives, however, are quite different; the only good replacements for expletives that I can think of right now would be similes or metaphors.

Comment: For many, the impact of words like _damn/damned_ and _bloody_ has been so diluted by long and frequent usage that they no longer register with listeners as swear words, but that isn't universally so.

Comment: Polite profanity loses much of the cathartic value of the unexpurgated form—but if you're looking for euphemisms to fill the empty spot in the phrase "That was so [modifier] hard," and you don't mind sounding a bit old-fashioned, you have a number of options with long pedigrees: _beggarly_, _blasted_, _confoundedly_, _cursedly_, _deuced_, and _demned_ (among others). If you want to give a vivid sense of the particular ill effects of the unpleasant experience, you can use a strong adverb such as _crushingly_, _debilitatingly_, _enervatingly_, _mind-numbingly_, _suffocatingly_, or _wretchedly_.

Comment: You mean *blistering barnacles!* *thundering typhoons*? http://tintin.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Captain_Haddock%27s_Curses

Comment: A lot of the effect from swearing comes from the pronunciation, so you actually get the same effect using some everyday word like 'bicycle' if you just pronounce it with enough force and in the same manner as you would a swear word. (also good to let out steam at work as it's safe everyday words). The added benefit is that you'll often perplex others at the same time.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Sadly, that won't work in comments. ;)

Comment: @SamuelLijin most of those aren't swearing, and many of them are rude. For a case of Shakespeare being polite with swearing, look rather at how he alludes to the word *cunt* without actually using the word. That is actually swearing, and at least pretending to be too polite to swear.

Answer (score 4):

Would I ever use any of these words... No, not most.  Would an author?  Probably not.  There is nothing wrong with using swear words in writing.  And if you are in a publication that you can't use them then you probably need to just explain or skip the exacts:

- Son of a Biscuit
- Son of a Beach
- Darn-it
- Crap
- Mother Trucker
- Dagnabit
- Good grief (Charilie Brown)
- Dang-it
- Yo-Yo Ma (Kramer)
- Serenity Now (George Costanza)
- Poo Poo head (kindergarteners)
- Bugger (A Christmas Story)
- Oh Fudge (A Christmas Story)

Comment: Note that when you use these, many listeners will know what they're euphemisms for - and may assume that you are usually in the habit of swearing, and stopped yourself at the last minute. It's not a good look for a primary school teacher. Trust me on this.

Comment: I feel obliged to point out that some of these are considered offensive swear words in their own right, at least in some regions.

Comment: @user867 - obviously you can't use all of these in all instances.  I will say this.  I am good friends with a priest.  The first 6 are his bread in butter - yes even Mother Trucker  You could use at least 4-5 of these in your job.

Comment: Bugger, is most certainly an offensive word. Crap is offensive to some, and acceptable to others.

Comment: @dwjohnston - Are you serious?  You are commenting on bugger but "so fricking hard" is fine to you?  I am not even sure where "bugger" is offensive.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd 'Bugger' is a sexual act. Saying 'I'll be buggered' or 'That's a bugger' certainly wouldn't go down well in some circles.

Comment: @dwjohnston - there is a good amount of words that are sex euphemisms.   I could say bugger in front of little kids and no one would flinch, not sure who you are hanging with.

Comment: I like thoooose!!! How can I get more of these phrases? any resources? lists?!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using euphemisms as *frack*, *frick*, *fracking*, *fricking*, *freaking*.

> **frack**: sanitized replacement for *fuck* used on Battlestar Galactica
>
> [frick](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Frick): euphemism for *fuck*
>
> [fricking](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fricking): a Southern and Midwestern slang word used to express excitement or anger without using profanity
>
> [freaking](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freaking): euphemism for *fucking*

*That was so [freaking](https://www.facebook.com/texantodd/posts/10201585031520119) (or [fricking](http://ah.roosterteeth.com/archive/?id=309&v=comments)) hard!*

Comment: To invoke punishment in a typical Catholic elementary school, the use of any of those f-words are fully as useful as the original.

Comment: also, *frell*, from Farscape. (and *dren*, too)

Answer (score 1):

> "That was so fucking hard".

There are lots of non-vulgar replacements. They tend to be a bit flowery:

That was like [carrying a horse up a ladder](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbeYtaL-2pQ).

That job was [tough as nails](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Tough%20As%20Nails).

That was like stuffing a ten inch rock into a five inch box. (many variants)

That felt like [herding cats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herding_cats).

Answer (score 0):

I commend to your attention [Chapter 3 of Job](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job%203&version=KJV) and the [beginning of Volume 3](http://www1.gifu-u.ac.jp/~masaru/TS/iii.36-59.html) of Laurence Sterne’s great comic novel *Tristram Shandy*—two of the greatest curses in literature. They are rather too elaborate to be the spontaneous overflow of powerful feelings. But once you have asked us lot and committed our answers to memory, spontaneity is out the window anyhow. Faux profanities, like the “Aw Jeez!” stereotyped on my current neighbors by the movie and TV show *Fargo,* are plentifully available as you can see here, but they tend to make the speaker sound tepid and ineffectual, namby-pamby. One might perhaps better cultivate a [laconic](http://books.google.com/books?id=bEJJAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=laconic%20style%20Simonides&source=bl&ots=JlmaAF2L7_&sig=vsvqykg5BmkAGdZ3d2kyDOYLuUA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GSKFU9-SKIKNqgaroIGYAQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=laconic%20style%20Simonides&f=false) and perhaps [litotic](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/L/litotes.htm) way of understatement, as for instance (your example) “that was not quite the easiest task I’ve ever finished.” Such use of litotes served some of the earlier users of English (like the *Beowulf* poet) to express powerful feelings inoffensively while sounding more hardy and stoical.